# jQuery DOM changes disappear after SharePoint list is sorted/filtered

Tags: jquery, sorting, dom, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have added jQuery code to a SharePoint Script Editor Webpart, which takes a document name (e.g., *my_doc.pdf*) adds the domain to it to create a full path and then wrap an `<a>` tag around a text which is on the next cell. This works perfectly on page load, but all DOM changes disappear upon sorting or filtering the list. here is the code (I replaced `$(document).ready` with `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push`):

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myDocURL");
 function myDocURL() {
  $('.ms-listlink').each(function(){
   var myDocName = $(this).attr('href'), 
       myDocNameHref = 'https://www.example.com' + myDocName;
       myDocLink = '<a href="' + myDocNameHref + '" target="_blank">',
       nextTD = $(this).closest("td").next();
   $(nextTD).wrapInner(myDocLink + '</a>');
 });
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Any reason you've opted to use a script editor web part instead of using the built-in [JSLink/Client Side Rendering](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried the JS Link option but it didn't work, the chnages to DOM didn't occur.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code you've tried? Maybe there's a subtle problem with your approach.

Comment: Thanks again @Thriggle. I added the code.

Comment: What SharePoint is it? If its 2013 then its a good idea to use `JSLink` as mentioned above and just change rendering of certain fields without using jQuery or attaching any events.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. Could you please elaborate a little on "change rendering of certain fields without using jQuery or attaching any events"?

Answer (score 2):

Text was too long for the comment, so here we go.

Here is a good article with examples on JSLink https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd
Its very easy and straight forward - no need for Script editors or other bizarre things.
Lets say you want to change "MyURL" field rendering.

```
// myrendering.js
(function () { 

    var ctx = {}; 
    ctx.Templates = {}; 
    ctx.Templates.Fields = { // you can override many things, but in this case we are going for the Fields
        // Apply the new rendering for MyURL field on List View 
        // But you can add as many fields as you like
        "MyURL": { "View": myUrlFieldTemplate }
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx); 

})();
// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
// Instead of default SharePoint url field you will get whatever you return from this function
function myUrlFieldTemplate(ctx) {  
    // put debugger here to see whats going on - it will help you alot  
    var myUrl = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; // get field value
    return "<a target='_blank' href='" + myUrl + "'>Im JSLink rendered field!</a>";
    // or you can return whatever you want, for example
    // return "<button>Im button now!</button>";
    // and your field "MyURL" will become a button in a list view
} 
//end
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently one way to keep the changes is by calling the function after every  `hashchange`:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", myFunction, false);
```